# Replacing NA's with a specific condition in R

Tags: r, replace, na

In case 2017 is NA and columns of 2015 and 2016 have value, I want to assign average of them to 2017 based on the same row.

```
Index   2015            2016            2017
1       NA              6355698         10107023
2       13000000        73050000        NA
4       NA              NA              NA
5       10500000        NA              8000000
6       331000000       659000000       1040000000
7       55500000        NA              32032920
8       NA              NA              20000000
9       2521880         5061370         7044288
...
```

Here is that I tried, didn't work!

```
ind <- which(is.na(df), arr.ind=TRUE)
df[ind] <- rowMeans(df,  na.rm = TRUE)[ind[,1]]
```

Also if we have values in 2015 and 2017 columns and 2016 is NA, I want to assign average of them to the column of 2016 based on the same row. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer: I'm not entirely clear on what your expected output is. My solution below is based on the assumption that you want to replace `NA` values with either the mean of all values for every year or with the mean value of all values for every `Index`.**

Here is a `tidyverse` option first spreading from wide to long, replacing `NA`s with the mean value per year, and finally converting back from long to wide.

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    gather(year, value, -Index) %>%
    group_by(year) %>%
    mutate(value = ifelse(is.na(value), mean(value, na.rm = T), value)) %>%
    spread(year, value)
## A tibble: 8 x 4
#  Index     `2015`     `2016`      `2017`
#  <int>      <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl>
#1     1 115507293.   6355698.   10107023.
#2     2  13000000. 223472356.  186197372.
#3     4 115507293. 223472356.  186197372.
#4     5 115507293. 223472356.    8000000.
#5     6 331000000. 659000000. 1040000000.
#6     7 115507293. 223472356.   32032920.
#7     8 115507293. 223472356.   20000000.
#8     9   2521880.   5061370.    7044288.
```

Note that here we replace `NA`s with mean value **per year**. If instead you want to replace `NA`s with the mean value **per `Index` value**, simply replace `group_by(year)` with `group_by(Index)`:

```
df %>%
    gather(year, value, -Index) %>%
    group_by(Index) %>%
    mutate(value = ifelse(is.na(value), mean(value, na.rm = T), value)) %>%
    spread(year, value)
## A tibble: 8 x 4
## Groups:   Index [8]
#  Index     `2015`     `2016`      `2017`
#  <int>      <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl>
#1     1   8231360.   6355698.   10107023.
#2     2  13000000.  13000000.   13000000.
#3     4       NaN        NaN         NaN
#4     5   8000000.   8000000.    8000000.
#5     6 331000000. 659000000. 1040000000.
#6     7  32032920.  32032920.   32032920.
#7     8  20000000.  20000000.   20000000.
#8     9   2521880.   5061370.    7044288.
```

---

### Update

To only replace `NA`s in column `2017` with the row average based on the `2015`,`2016` values you can do

```
df <- read_table("Index   2015            2016            2017
1       NA              6355698         10107023
2       13000000        73050000        NA
4       NA              NA              NA
5       10500000        NA              8000000
6       331000000       659000000       1040000000
7       55500000        NA              32032920
8       NA              NA              20000000
9       2521880         5061370         7044288")


df %>%
    mutate(`2017` = ifelse(is.na(`2017`), 0.5 * (`2015` + `2016`), `2017`))
## A tibble: 8 x 4
#  Index    `2015`    `2016`      `2017`
#  <int>     <int>     <int>       <dbl>
#1     1        NA   6355698   10107023.
#2     2  13000000  73050000   43025000.
#3     4        NA        NA         NA
#4     5  10500000        NA    8000000.
#5     6 331000000 659000000 1040000000.
#6     7  55500000        NA   32032920.
#7     8        NA        NA   20000000.
#8     9   2521880   5061370    7044288.
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read_table("Index   2015            2016            2017
1       NA              6355698         10107023
2       13000000        NA              NA
4       NA              NA              NA
5       NA              NA              8000000
6       331000000       659000000       1040000000
7       NA              NA              32032920
8       NA              NA              20000000
9       2521880         5061370         7044288")
```

Comment: Should it be `group_by(Index)`? As OP is searching rowMeans?

Comment: @Jimbou Hmm. Yes, perhaps. I'm a bit confused, because in that case `Index = 4` will have all `NA`s. I'll make a note.

Comment: Thanks guys! I edited the sample data because the previous one didn't have what I want you show you as an example

Comment: @kimi-finn379 So you only want to replace `NA`s for the year 2017?

Comment: For 2017 and 2016. To clarify average of columns must be based on the same row as well

Comment: Not clear. *"In case 2017 is NA and columns of 2015 and 2016 have value, I want to assign average of them to 2017 based on the same row."* So you only want to replace `NA` values in column `2017`. `NA`s in columns `2015` and `2016` will stay the same. Correct?

Comment: @kimi-finn379 I've included an update where I show how to replace `NA`s in column `2017` with the row average from the `2015`/`2016` values.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I want. Sorry for the bad explanation.

Comment: @kimi-finn379 No problem and you're very welcome!

Comment: In case I want to remove rows which have 2 or 3 NA's in the column of 2015, 2016, 2017. What can I do?

Comment: @kimi-finn379 To remove rows with `>= 2` `NA`s per row you can do `df[apply(df, 1, function(x) sum(is.na(x)) < 2), ]`